# Selenium на Ubuntu сервере: tab crashed

Tags: python, ubuntu

Есть парсер который парсит данные и сохраняет их в список потом достает из списка и сохраняет каждую инфу отдельно в файлы и все это работает в цикле. Код прекрасно работает, но на сервере перестало работать. И дает ошибку

```
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
(Session info: headless chrome=107.0.5304.110)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x5573b5246463
```

... и т.д. цифры как сверху

Скрипт сохраняет данные в список но не создает файл и не записывает в файл данные из списка.
Сервер на ubuntu, обычный vds/vps сервер

```
#Библиотеки
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

#Ссылка на сайт
URL = 'https://equanity.notion.site/af08990fbca340b38301653a7da4c9c3'

#Настройки веб-драйвера
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

#Путь к веб-драйверу
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/home/tbot/chromedriver",options = options)
driver.maximize_window()

#Получаем название и ссылки всех кнопок в главной странице (Карта Гайда))
def get_info():
    while True:
        try:
            driver.get(url=URL)
            time.sleep(7)
            source = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
            all_buttons_get = soup.find_all(class_ = "pseudoSelection")
            buttons_name = []
            buttons_href = []

            for item in all_buttons_get:
                try:
                    item_text = item.text
                    item_href = "https://equanity.notion.site" + item.find('a')['href']
                    buttons_name.append(item_text)
                    buttons_href.append(item_href)
                except Exception as ex:print(ex)
            del buttons_name[0:2]
            file = open("/home/tbot/name.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8")
            file.write("\n".join(buttons_name).join("\n"))
            print(buttons_name)
            print(buttons_href)
            for inf in buttons_name:
                file.write("%s\n" %inf)
            file.close()
        except Exception as ex:print(ex)
        #Получем информацию внутрий кнопок 2-уровня
        count = 1
        try:
            del buttons_href[0:2]
            for hrefs in buttons_href:
                driver.get(url=hrefs)
                time.sleep(7)
                source_2 = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source_2, 'lxml')
                text = [i.text for i in soup.find_all('div', class_='notion-selectable')]
                li = []
                for i in text:
                    if i not in li:
                       li.append(i)
                del li[0:6]
                #Полученную инфу записываем в файлы
                file = open(f"/home/tbot/data/{count}_info.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8")
                file.write("\n".join(li).join("\n"))

                for item in li:
                    file.write("%s\n" % item)
                file.close()
                count += 1
        except Exception as ex:print(ex)
        time.sleep(85500)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_info()
```